# Exibir/Ocultar os meta caracteres

Tags: sublime-text-2

Como eu faria para com um clique alterar a exibição dos meta caracteres no sublime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utilizando um [resposta que encontrei](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/keybinding-draw-white-space-toggle/5122) no internet, através de um plugin:

1º Passo :

```
Tools->New Plugin...
```

Colar o seguinte código:

```
import sublime, sublime_plugin

class ToggleWhiteSpaceCommand(sublime_plugin.ApplicationCommand):
    def run(self):
        settings = sublime.load_settings("Preferences.sublime-settings")
        white_space = "selection" if settings.get("draw_white_space", "selection") != "selection" else "all"
        settings.set("draw_white_space", white_space)
        sublime.save_settings("Preferences.sublime-settings")
```

Salve como `toggle_white_space.py`. (Pode ser outro nome, mas vai influenciar no passo 2).

2º Passo :

```
Preferences->Key Bindings - User
```

Adicionar um linha com

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+shift+'"], "command": "toggle_white_space" },
            ^ Keys a serem precionadas  ^ Nome do arquivo a ser executado
              para ativar o comando
```